# Merge two big files

Tags: vb.net, merge

I need to join two text files together, but I don't just want to add one to the other, but rather add the lines of the first file until I find a word, then the same for the second, then back to the first and continue the cycle until I run out of both files .

I have the following code, which works (but takes a long time) with files of around 50k lines, but the files I need to merge are around 2kk lines.

```
Private Sub Juntar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Juntar.Click
        Gravar.Enabled = False
        System.IO.File.Delete("c:\temp\tempfile.txt")

        Do Until (Prog_1_Button.Enabled = True And Prog_2_Button.Enabled = True)
            While Not (Prog_1_Button.Enabled)
                lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file1).ToList
                arrayLines = lines.ToArray
                Dim i As Integer = lines.IndexOf(Array.Find(arrayLines, Function(x) (x.Contains("teste"))))
                saida = lines.GetRange(0, i + 1)
                lines.RemoveRange(0, i + 1)

                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file1, lines)
                If i >= 0 Then
                    Prog_Bar.Value = Prog_Bar.Value + i
                    Exit While
                Else
                    saida = lines
                    Prog_1_Button.Enabled = True
                End If
            End While
            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("c:\temp\tempfile.txt", saida)
            saida.Clear()
            While Not (Prog_2_Button.Enabled)
                lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file2).ToList
                arrayLines = lines.ToArray
                Dim i As Integer = lines.IndexOf(Array.Find(arrayLines, Function(x) (x.Contains("teste"))))
                saida = lines.GetRange(0, i + 1)
                lines.RemoveRange(0, i + 1)

                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(file2, lines)
                If i >= 0 Then
                    Prog_Bar.Value = Prog_Bar.Value + i
                    Exit While
                Else
                    saida = lines
                    Prog_2_Button.Enabled = True
                End If
            End While

            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("c:\temp\tempfile.txt", saida)
            saida.Clear()
        Loop
        Gravar.Enabled = True

    End Sub
```

Example:

```
**file_1:**
aaa1
bbb1
**teste**1
ccc1
ddd1
**teste**1


**file_2:**
aaa2
bbb2
**teste**2
ccc2
ddd2
**teste**2

**output:**
aaa1
bbb1
**teste**1
aaa2
bbb2
**teste**2
ccc1
ddd1
**teste**1
ccc2
ddd2
**teste**2
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data (an example file of less than 10 lines would be enough) + desired output, just to make sure I get your textual explanation of what you want to happen.

Comment: I added an example to my question. I hope it is perceptible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do it (much simpler):

I created a console app so, you might need to add the GUI stuff, or not because that's one of the things that can slow down your app.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())

        Dim lines1() As String = File.ReadAllLines("d:\\temp\\input1.txt")
        Dim lines2() As String = File.ReadAllLines("d:\\temp\\input2.txt")
        Dim newfile As System.IO.StreamWriter
        newfile = New StreamWriter("d:\\temp\\output.txt", False)

        Dim i2 As Integer = 0
        For i1 = 0 To lines1.Count - 1
            newfile.WriteLine(lines1(i1))
            If (lines1(i1).Contains("teste")) Then
                For j = i2 To lines2.Count - 1
                    newfile.WriteLine(lines2(j))
                    i2 = j + 1
                    If (lines2(j).Contains("teste")) Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
        For j = i2 To lines2.Count - 1
            newfile.WriteLine(lines2(j))
        Next
        newfile.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've done some tests and it seems to be exactly what I need.